# Tableau, orient color of datapoints on scatterplot

Tags: plot, data-visualization, tableau-api, color-scheme

I am plotting two undesireable statistics

Columns: AGG(%SEP11)

Row: AGG(%Outdated_Defs)

This is how my graph looks. Only the points that have 50% or more installations of SEP 11 are red, even if they have high % of outdated defs.

[image]

I wish to make is such that sites with high % of outdated defs are also red, i.e.

[image]

In other words, only bottom left side of scatterplot should have green dots, remaining should have shades of red where top right quadrant had the most deep red dots.

Please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to create a calculated field called `bad_color`:

```
IF AGG(%SEP11) >= 0.5 OR AGG(%Outdated_Defs) >= 0.5 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
```

Then drag `bad_color` to the color field.  Doubleclick on the color field and select red for 1 and green for 0.

Comment: Trying this out, getting errors with the syntax of calculated field, researching this ......

Comment: Since I'm guessing you calculated the aggregates/percentiles in the plot, you may need to specify the percentile function in the calculated field as well.

Comment: Now I fixed calculated field but all green points. Will research the percentile function

Comment: Maybe you need to replace 0.5 with 50? as in 50%

Comment: I replaced 0.5 with 50 and now the reds and greens are inverted, i.e. bottom left is red, but it's supposed to be green. Troubleshooting this ........

Comment: Switch the colors by double clicking on color on the marks bar and selecting which color goes to which number.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/87509/discussion-between-sohni-mahiwal-and-charlie-haley).

Comment: FYI, you can simplify a bit by defining bad_color simply as the condition part of the if statement, i.e. "%SEP11 >= 0.5 or %Outdated_Defs >= 0.5". That creates a boolean valued field. Boolean expressions are first class citizens. No need to wrap an if statement around a condition just to return the condition.